# How do I create a fake facebook access token in Android for testing?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a graph request using the facebook SDK as such:

```
GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken, this);
```

In my `onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse)` callback, I would like to handle any errors. Currently, I have it set as such:

```
if (graphResponse.getError() != null) {
  // I intend to raise make a toast and display any errors here to the user.
  Log.d(TAG, graphResponse.getError().toString());
}
```

Is there an easy way to create a bad AccessToken so that I can catch the error? The docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/#constructors) specify a constructor for it but it is pretty tedious.

I'm running Facebook SDK 4.0.1 for Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the real access token via the normal login flow, then invalidate it using [an API call](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/permissions#Deleting)[1] or by uninstalling the app from your [Facebook privacy settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications), which will invalidate the token

[1] - As of today, there's a bug with the documentation and it says you can't use that endopoint to remove permissions, but a DELETE request to `/<user>/permissions` will remove your app from that user's profile and invalidate all tokens for that user/app pair